# Calorie Counter Calculator for Computer Science 1

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator

```
System.out.print("Your BMR is:");//BMR Calculation
        if (gender == ('M')){
            System.out.println(665+(6.23 * weight)+(12.7 * height)-(6.8 * age));

        } else if (gender == ('F')) {
            System.out.println(655+(4.35 * weight)+(4.7 * height)-(4.7 * age));

        };
```

I can get the result from the if-loop above to produce the BMR. However, I can't seem to get the BMR result to be input into the bottom if-loop to produce the exercise calculation.

```
System.out.println("What is your exercise routine, on the scale of 0 to 4? 0 is lowest and 4 is highest ");//Exercise Calculation
        int exercise = sc.nextInt();
        if (exercise == 0) {
            System.out.println(BMR * 1.2);
        } else if (exercise == 1) {
            System.out.println(BMR * 1.375);
        } else if (exercise == 2) {
            System.out.println(BMR * 1.55);
        } else if (exercise == 3) {
            System.out.println(BMR * 1.725);
        }else if (exercise == 4) {
            System.out.println(BMR * 1.9);
        };
```

Comment: You need to save the result of the calculation to a variable. You even use the variable BMR in the lower part.

Comment: *"if-loop"* The `if` *statement* is not a loop. `for`, `while`, and `do-while` are loops, because they can execute the body of the statement multiple times, i.e. they can **loop back** and do it again. The `if` *statement* makes a *choice*, and will conditionally execute the body of the `if` (or `else` if present), depending on the condition, but it will not loop back and do it again.

Comment: How do I save the result of the calculation to a variable?

Comment: **Don't** compare strings with `==`. Use `equals` instead.

Comment: @QuocLe how to save? Just define the variable:  `float bmr =  665+(6.23 * weight)+(12.7 * height)-(6.8 * age);`  and afterwards you can print it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be storing the value of BMR into a local variable so that you can access it later on in your code.

Here's an example:

```
System.out.print("Your BMR is:");//BMR Calculation
double BMR = 0;
if (gender == ('M')){
    BMR = 665+(6.23 * weight)+(12.7 * height)-(6.8 * age);
    System.out.println(BMR);

} else if (gender == ('F')) {
    BMR = 655+(4.35 * weight)+(4.7 * height)-(4.7 * age);
    System.out.println(BMR);

};
```

And then you can use that BMR double variable later on.

Comment: @QuocLe No problem! Good luck with your project!